# How to pass a variable into multiple functions

Tags: php, class, oop, variables

In my screenshot below you can see I have a list of functions that run a routine, fairly in-depth routine.

Previously, I have ben repeating this routine in multiple classes, but now I would like to consolidate those multiple classes into one class and execute only one function, by passing a variable into that function to determine the output to return.

I know how to pass the variable into "one" function, but how can I pass the variable ($this_id) into my multiple functions below? Basically, whatever $this_id is from get_output($this_id); I want that same variable value to be carried over into the other $this_id functions. See screenshot...

I searched online and all answers I've seen show how to do this in a non static way, but I'm only familiar with calling things statically, really. I tried the obj way, but couldn't get it to work.

Example, execution...

```
$header = 'CustomTheme_output';
$header::get_output('header');
```

***(please disregard any lose code, the code is what I have so far from trying multiple ways. private $id and __construct are from the online solutions I have been trying)***

Could you please clue me in on how I can correctly achieve this? I would be sooo happy to get rid of all the repetitive code, folders and files I have! - Thanks!

[image]

Comment: never post a screenshot. copy paste the code so we don't have to type it out.

Comment: I didn't because my code is longer than any code I've seen in a SO post. It would be somewhere near 1500 lines of code. I feel I captured the essence of what I am saying and need to achieve that another dev could understand without the need to read code that really has nothing to do with my real objective/question. I made the judgement (I think is sound) that all the code was not needed to tell me how to answer this and I think I can stand by that because if I knew how and someone else posted the same I could easily answer them. If you think my question should be worded better, let me know.

Comment: Just stopping by too. I didn't know devs were actually typing the code out. Sorry I missed that in my first response. Thanks for mentioning it. Will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either you pass it directly into each method call:

```
public function foo($this_id) {
     $this->bar($this_id);
}
```

Or you make it a class attribute, and simply ACCESS it from the various methods:

```
public function foo($this_id) {
    $this->id = $this_id;
    $this->bar();
}

public function bar() {
   do_something($this->id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So this non-static way has me a little confused because I'm new to it, I expect. Could you provide an example with the function from my screenshot so I can better understand? It sounds like you're saying for each of my output functions I should run public function UniqueName_output($this_id) { $this->get_output($this_id) Then my code... } ?